# Bitcoin PPA installation problem

Tags: 11.10, command-line, ppa, bitcoin

Im trying to download Bitcoin for my Ubuntu Oneiric.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install bitcoin/bitcoin
```

Everything goes smooth until the install line.

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package bitcoin
```

Help! I've never done a PPA before!

Comment: just try to install bitcoin-qt instead just bitcoin

Answer (score 8):

I got it installed and working with these. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

- Add the [Bitcoin Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin) repository in your Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
  ```
- Update package lists

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install [`bitcoin-qt`](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin/+sourcepub/2996765/+listing-archive-extra)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
  ```

Ready! Look for Bitcoin under "Applications menu"

Answer (score -1):

The problem appears to be the `apt-get install` command you gave:

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin/bitcoin
```

Looking in [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin), the package you want is just called `bitcoin`, so this is probably what you wanted to type:

```
sudo apt-get install bitcoin
```

Comment: I did that. I got the same error.

Comment: Okay.  Two things to check: (1) was there any errors printed by `apt-get update`? and (2) What does `apt-cache policy bitcoin` show?  Try editing your question to include this info.

Comment: $ apt-cache policy bitcoin                                            N: Unable to locate package bitcoin>
and there was one error in the update:                          W: Failed to fetch http://download.tuxfamily.org/syzygy42/dists/feisty/avant-window-navigator/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 88.191.250.171 80]

Comment: That `download.tuxfamily.org` update error looks unrelated (although you may as well remove that source -- even if it worked you probably don't want to install software targeted at Ubuntu 7.04).  I'm left wondering whether the PPA was actually added correctly.  Were any errors returned by the `apt-add-repository`?